# USB not detected on 12.04

Tags: usb-drive

I am a new user using ubuntu 12.04. When I put my STRONTIUM pen drive in laptop it is not detected by my laptop. So how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you see anything when you open the program disks? (use 'gnome-disks' in the terminal for faster access) - does it show up there?

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam--sorry .. the command 'qnome-disks' doesn't work. when i am typing it on TERMINAl it shows command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the command `sudo df -Th` and check out for "vfat" in the Type column of the output.
If "vfat" exists, your pen drive is detected and you should check it on Nautilus file manager. 
If it doesn't exists, maybe your pen drive doesn't compatible with Linux.